# How can I provide lateral support for hydronic baseboard pipe?

Tags: plumbing, baseboard, support, brackets, hydronic

I am renovating a room that has slant fin baseboard. I want to replace the slant fin hardware (cover) with a different cover style. These are high output pipes that run horizontal to each other.

The problem is over time, the pipes are no longer plumb to the wall. They've drifted about an inch from one side to the other, which is a eight foot span. What I want to do is plumb the pipes and secure them to the wall so that it's plumb from one side to the other on that eight foot span. What I'd like to do is pull the pipes closer for the wall with some kind of hanger, brace, etc.

The wall has base moulding on concrete to secure it to.

How can I support these pipes so they're square to the wall and floor?

Comment: Normally the brackets that hold the cover parts in place also hold the pipes in place. Please [edit] to add some pictures of your setup.

Comment: "Plumb" usually refers to vertical (see: plumb bob). "Square" usually means in alignment with something else. "Horizontal" means aligned with the horizon (see: spirit level). Do you really want your baseboard heaters "plumb"? Providing pics will help us to know if the piping is not level, or if it drifts away from the wall (not square), or what, exactly the issue is, since your word picture is a bit vague.

Comment: I cannot upload photos as they exceed maximum size